# GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM not displaying information

Tags: git, bash

In my `.bashrc` file I have included the following:

```
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="verbose git"

export PS1="\t]\[\e[${ps_color}m\]\h:\w\[\e[0m\] \$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')> "
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
11:31:12]boxname:~/deploy/config/deploy (master %)>
```

Now at the same time I get this message from a `git status`

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
```

Which would leave me to believe my prompt should be

```
11:31:12]boxname:~/deploy/config/deploy (master % +3)>
```

Any ideas why I can't get this to work properly?  I'm on a centos6 box running gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my system the git completion script was being accessed from

```
/etc/git.bash
```

I was able to update to the newest version of the git completion by linking to

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/git
```

with a simple

```
$ ln -s /etc/bash_completion.d/git git.bash
```